# Failing to recieve Activities data from youtube data api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've tried to build an app that makes a youtube-api activities list request every x seconds, to look for new things that happened on some channels.
The code works fine but some channels give me no response back about the activities. The request will work fine and give no error but there are no data.

Hope you know what I mean and somebody has a solution for me.

Tried it also here : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list

but same problem - request is successful but no items inside.

Comment: Can you share one of the channel ID that returns empty activities data?

Comment: Here one of the ids : UCJgcqQq2WyJf35ovKj8fFeQ

Comment: Yes I also get a 200 successful request code, but zero items in the JSON response. Are you looking for specific new things, like simply new uploads, or other activity as well? There might be other API methods to get the data.

Comment: I`m looking for new uploads to generate an automatic webhook post to discord. The api request with the activities and the publishedAfter filter is a nice and fast solution to do this (if it works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also was unable to get new uploads information for that channel ID using the `Activities:List` API request. However, I was able to use a different API request (actually a series of two) and successfully get the 50 most recent uploads.

If you only need uploads, as your comment suggests, this could be a solution. It uses [Channels:List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) and [PlaylistItems:List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API requests, at a quota cost of one unit each:

First, the Channels:List call retrieves the uploads playlist ID:
get playlist ID:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=UCJgcqQq2WyJf35ovKj8fFeQ&maxResults=10&fields=items&order=date&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The response from Youtube contains JSON code:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/JLM6UA_xPnpiDQtL6ILexatJ0sc\"",
   "id": "UCJgcqQq2WyJf35ovKj8fFeQ",
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
```

> "uploads": "UUJgcqQq2WyJf35ovKj8fFeQ",

```
     "watchHistory": "HL",
     "watchLater": "WL"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
```

Using the **uploads** playlist ID from the above response, make the PlaylistItems:List call. `Max-results` sets up to 50 latest items:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&fields=nextPageToken,items(snippet(publishedAt,title,description,thumbnails(default(url)),resourceId(videoId)))&playlistId=UUJgcqQq2WyJf35ovKj8fFeQ&maxResults=50&order=date&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The response contains 50 most recent videos, date-sorted. Including publish date, title, description, thumbnail image url, video ID , and nextpage token (used if you want to get 50 more items):

```
{
 "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-06-07T18:30:01.000Z",
    "title": "BATMAN a Telltale Story | Folge 22 [Deutsch LP]",
    "description": "! Willkommen Freund von #GamingausLeidenschaft !\n\nFolge 22 zeigt wer der wahre maskierte Rächer Gothams ist.\n\n!!Viel Spass!!\n****************************** \nDir gefällt was ich mache? \nDann lass es am besten alle wissen und schlag doch \netwas den Subscribe/Abobutton der braucht Nähe ;)\nDu warst nicht Zufrieden?\nDann lass dir freien Lauf das in den Kommentaren zu erwähnen :)\nJede Form von Feedback sehe ich als Support!\n******************************\nTweet me: twitter@brille591 \n******************************\nDiscord Server : https://discord.gg/eRwmFM\n******************************\nFalls du möchtest kannst du mir unter diesem Link:\n\nhttps://streamlabs.com/Skarkerino\n\nein kleines Trinkgeld zukommen lassen \n(alles wird in Equipment und Qualitätsverbesserung gesteckt) \nAktuelles Ziel: RAM\n******************************\nÜBER DIESES SPIEL\nBatman: The Telltale Series ist ein am 2. August 2016 veröffentlichtes Computerspiel des Entwicklers Telltale Games. \nDatum der Erstveröffentlichung: 2. August 2016\n-\nSpiel-Engine: Telltale Tool\nSprache: Englisch (Audio), Deutsch (Untertitel)\nHerausgeber: Telltale Games\nPlattformen: PlayStation 4, Android, Nintendo Switch, Xbox One, PlayStation 3, Xbox 360, Microsoft Windows, iOS\nDesigner: Mark Darin, Michael Kirkbride\n\n#BATMAN\n#Telltale\n#Brille591\n#Optiksquad\n#Deutsch\n#LP\n#DC\n#WB",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZZSDYaW0nxw/default.jpg"
     }
    },
    "resourceId": {
     "videoId": "ZZSDYaW0nxw"
    }
   }
  }, ... etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast help !! Looks like that the uploads code is nearly the same as the channel code so i think it will be the same all time and i can save it for periodically check and by limit the request with maxResult and check for new by look at publishedAt I will make it run.

Comment: Yes, by default if `order=date`, the first item is the newest video. If you do max-results of only 1, you will only get the most recent 1 video. (This is in the second API request)